# The events are not getting removed when draggable attribute is set to false

Tags: javascript, svg

var attachEvents=(function(){
          var events="click mouseover mouseout mousedown mouseup mousemove keydown keyup dragstart dragend drag".split(" ");
          for(var i=0;i
            })(events[i]);
           }
      })();
        Object.prototype.draggable=function(f){
          this.setAttribute("draggable",f);
          var currentX,currentY,clickX,clickY;

```
         function mouseMove(e){
         e.preventDefault(); 
         if(this.getAttribute("click")=="true"){
            currentX+=e.clientX-clickX;
            currentY+=e.clientY-clickY;
            clickX+=e.clientX-clickX;
            clickY+=e.clientY-clickY;
            if(this.hasAttribute("cx")){
             this.setAttribute("cx",currentX);
             this.setAttribute("cy",currentY);   
            }
            else{
             this.setAttribute("x",currentX);
             this.setAttribute("y",currentY);
            }

             }
         };
        function mouseDown(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            this.setAttribute("click","true");
            click=true;
            clickX=e.clientX;
            clickY=e.clientY;
         };
       function mouseUp(){
            this.setAttribute("click","false");
        };
        if(this.getAttribute("draggable")=="true"){
         if(this.hasAttribute("cx")){
             currentX=Number(this.getAttribute("cx"));
             currentY=Number(this.getAttribute("cy"));
             this.mousedown(mouseDown);
             this.mouseup(mouseUp);
             this.mousemove(mouseMove);  
         }      
         else{
             currentX=Number(this.getAttribute("x"));
             currentY=Number(this.getAttribute("y"));
             this.mousedown(mouseDown);
             this.mouseup(mouseUp);
             this.mousemove(mouseMove); 
         }
      }
      else if(this.getAttribute("draggable")=="false"){
          this.unmousedown(mouseDown);
          this.unmouseup(mouseUp);
          this.unmousemove(mouseMove);
      }
  };
```

Comment: Here is the function that attaches and  removes the events:-

Comment: var attachEvents=(function(){
          var events="click mouseover mouseout mousedown mouseup mousemove keydown keyup dragstart dragend drag".split(" ");
          for(var i=0;i<events.length;i++){
           var attach=(function(eventName){
               Object.prototype[eventName]=function(){
              this.addEventListener(eventName,arguments[0],false);
              }; 
              Object.prototype["un"+eventName]=function(){
              this.removeEventListener(eventName,arguments[0],false);
              };  
            })(events[i]);
           }
      })();

Comment: add the function to the question (you can use the 'edit' button)

Comment: Add some more description to the ticket.